# Python Tkinter - Is there a method that disable the instant preview of the tk.PanedWindow

Tags: python, tkinter

The Tkinter paned window provide us an interface to resize the content of the buttons and entries. However, the paned window resize immediately while the user drag the slide bar. I don't want this. I want that the window resize after the user drag the slide bar and release it. Is there any method to achieve this?

this is my code

```
import tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk(); root.title("Paned Window ")
btn1=tk.Button(text="1")
btn2=tk.Button(text="2")
t=tk.PanedWindow(root)
t.add(btn1);t.add(btn2)
t.set_resize_after_drag(True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Firstly, use some spaces... Your code has a relatively lower readability... let me fix that.

Use `opaqueresize`. The default is `True`. However, it's your turn to change it to `False`.

```py
# Importing module
import tkinter as tk

# Creating window
root=tk.Tk()

# Creating the window
root.title("Paned Window")

# Creating widgets
btn1=tk.Button(text="1")
btn2=tk.Button(text="2")

# Creating the Paned window
t=tk.PanedWindow(root)

# Adding buttons to it...
t.add(btn1)
t.add(btn2)

# Configuring the paned window
t.configure(opaqueresize=False)  # The default is True. You can made it to False.
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the canonical tcl/tk documentation, you can set `opaqueresize` to `False`:

*"Specifies whether panes should be resized as a sash is moved (true), or if resizing should be deferred until the sash is placed (false). In the latter case, a “ghost” version of the sash is displayed during the resizing to show where the panes will be resized to when releasing the mouse button. This “ghost” version of the sash is the proxy. It's rendering can be configured using the **proxybackground**, **proxyborderwidth** and **proxyrelief** options."*

```
t=tk.PanedWindow(root, opaqueresize=False)
```